# unable to collapse using Bootstrap Collapse

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a website which is used to display the news using vertically collapsing accordions.I'm using an external API to fetch the news.
I need only news to be visible at a time.
When I click on the 2nd news title, I need the 1st news description to be hidden/collapsed. Similarly, when I click on any of the news , I want the rest to be kept collapsed/hidden , but this doesn't work . (See [web page snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i97nc.png))

Here are the html and JS codes.

JS :

```js
let display = document.getElementById("display");
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;

xhr.open("GET", "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-news&apiKey=70893d07e43d413faf7813e13df0f8aa", true)

xhr.onload = function () {
    let strHtml = "";
    if (this.status === 200) {
        let newsObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        let newsArticles = newsObj.articles;

        console.log(newsArticles)

        newsArticles.forEach(function (element, index) {      //newsArticle --> an array which contains the news data including the title and description of the news

            let str = `<div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading${index}">
              <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse${index}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse${index}">
                ${element.title}
              </button>
            </h2>
            
            <div id="collapse${index}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading${index}" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
              <div class="accordion-body">
                <strong>  ${element.description}</strong>
                <a href="${element.url}" target="_blank" <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Learn more</button> </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            
          </div>`

            strHtml += str;        //append news data into strHtml string 
        });
    }
    else {
        console.log("some error")
    }

    display.innerHTML = strHtml;         //to display the news on the page

}

xhr.send();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BBC News</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false"
                aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button"
                            data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                            Dropdown
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <hr class="dropdown-divider">
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="d-flex">
                    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container my-3">
        <h3><span class="badge bg-primary">Top news</span>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="container accordionExample" >
        <div class="accordion" id="display">

        </div>
        
    </div>
</div>

    <script src="./JS/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: data-bs-parent="heading${index}" ?

Comment: Post your code here and if there are, the errors. No images.

Comment: Edited the post with HTML and JS codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `<div>` around your accordion with a parent ID:

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
```

And in your `.collapse` element you need that

```
 data-bs-parent="#accordionExample"
```

You already have that. So I guess it's just the missing wrapper.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot ! 
I just used <div class="container accordion" id="accordionExample"> in my html code.

Comment: nice to hear ;-)

Answer (score 0):

trying replacing the 'str' variable with the below one. It should work then.

```
let str = `<div class="card">
        <div class="accordion-header" id="heading${index}">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
                <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse${index}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse${index}">
                ${element.title}
                </button>
            </h5>
        </div>

        <div id="collapse${index}" class="collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading${index}">
            <div class="accordion-body">
            <strong>  ${element.description}</strong>
            <a href="${element.url}" target="_blank" <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Learn more</button> </a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>`
```

Comment: Didn't work....

Comment: I had tried it on my local. It worked for me. Or you can do another thing, just change the bootstrap version to previous one , you're using the latest one. It looks like it has got some issues with accordion. @AshishPradhan